# How to show exponential smooth on chartjs graph?

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I'm trying to build a chart with 2 curves. For instance, I did 30 pieces of training, and I have the array with some numbers for each training `const trainingsDataSet = [24, 23, 89, 10, 88...]`. It should be the first curve. On the second curve, I want to show exponential smooth for this 30 trainings. Like on this picture. [image: exponential]

Is it possible to do it with chartjs? Should I use a multiple line chart or I need to initialize 2 different charts?

I have prepared [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exps?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts). To calculate smooth curve I use [savitzky-golay libraly](https://github.com/mljs/savitzky-golay). But I think it's the wrong decision. Do you guys have any ideas or advice?